# Drupal Views: How can I log searches?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

Is there a module that allows me to log all the searches made on a view ?

Thanks !

Comment: With searches made on a view, do you mean by using an exposed filter in a view?

Comment: Zilverdistel, Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to write custom code to achieve that! I'm assuming you know some basics about writing Drupal custom code. You will need to use a hook that gets called before your view is displayed. In the hook you should log whatever information you want e.g. the keyword that was entered in the exposed filter.

Please see http://drupalcontrib.org/api/group/views_hooks/6 for the hooks that are available to you in Views.

I'm guessing you would probably use something like `hook_views_pre_render`